# Crystal Reports: multiple parameter values in record selection filter

Tags: crystal-reports

I created a report with:

Parameter: 
buildingIds: String

Allow Multiple Values:  True

Record Filter
{WO.BL_ID} in [{?buildingIds}]

The designer gives me error: "An array cannot be an element of another array."

How do I pass multiple values for a parameter, that is used in "in list" filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `[]`:

```
 {WO.BL_ID} IN {?buildingIds}
```